# Porque meu countdowntimer trata o tempo recebido de acordo com o celular

Tags: java, android

Tenho um countdowntimer que recebe um valor long de 86400000 ( 24 horas ) no meu emulador do android 5.1 ele reconhece 24 horas e começa contar desde de então, mas em outros emuladores e no meu celular fisico ele não começa em 24 horas, ele começa em 20, 18 horas, varia o tempo de dispositivo. não estou entendendo.

Código do meu countdowntimer

```
private void contagemregressiva(final long temporestante) {
        Log.d(TAG,"tempo restante recebido na contagem: " + temporestante);
        new CountDownTimer(temporestante, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
                Date date = new Date(millisUntilFinished);

                txv_temporestante.setText(dateFormat.format(date));
                temporestanteaa = millisUntilFinished;
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                dados.setDia(dados.getDia()+1);
                dados.setContagemVirou(true);
                atualizarUI();
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido, era problemas com localidade, para não sofrer deste problema, formate a hora assim:

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                long second = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;
                long minute = (millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
                long hour = (millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;

                String time = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
                txv_temporestante.setText(time);
                temporestanteaa = millisUntilFinished;
            }
```